# No such signature was found on Play Console

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-developers-console

I have some issues with the signature of my apk created in Unity. I've followed these steps:

1. Built the apk with the Unity Build Settings
2. Created a keystore with Unity Keystore Manager
3. Signed the apk with the following command
   **jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore mykeystore.keystore myapk.apk alias**
4. Aligned the signed apk with the following command:
   **zipalign -f -v 4 myapk.apk zipalignedapk.apk**

At this point, I try loading the zipaligned apk on the Google Play Console release page, but I'm getting this error:

*"You loaded an APK with a non valid signature. Error in apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer CERT.RSA): JAR signature META-INF/CERT.SF indicates the APK is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2 but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?"*

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Is there any different procedure to sign an APK for Play Console using Unity?

Thanks all.